Data race in the code snippet mentioned in other SO which read/write could not be invoked in the same time
The code below is seen at this SO except the comment in the original question has been removed.
std::weak_ptr<int> g_w;

void f3()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int>l_s3 = g_w.lock(); //2. here will read g_w
    if (l_s3)
    {
        ;/.....
    }
}

void f4()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> p_s = std::make_shared<int>(1);
    g_w = p_s;

    std::thread th(f3);
    th.detach();
}

Although, the same object of weak_ptr(i.e. g_w) is read and written by two different threads, updating g_w in f4() is before the constructation of thread object (i.e. std::thread th(f3);) in which reading g_w via g_w.lock() is invoked. The two operations could not be run at the same time. So I think the code snippet is correct and no data race would occur.
I have read the comments of the said SO again and again but I really can't understand, say.

Updating g_w in f4() and at the same time reading g_w via g_w.lock() in f3() is undefined behaviour!


"The two operations could not be run at the same time. " why not?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Updating g_w in f4() is called before the constructation of thread object (i.e. std::thread th(f3);) in which reading g_w via g_w.lock() is invoked. You see, g_w = p_s; is written before std::thread th(f3);.

how about the comment in the code // 1. p_s destory will motify g_w (write g_w) ? Destroying p_s will modify g_w while potentially the other thread reads

how is this not a duplicate of the question you link? If the answer needs to be clarified then it should be done on the answer not elsewhere

@463035818_is_not_an_ai There is a debate about the mentioned comment. I don't really understand what the OP mean by the comment. If we do not consider the said comment(I will revert the question), any potential problem in the code?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai The anwers in the aforementioned SO focus on talking about under what conditions is or is not thread-safe. No answer or comment could directly answer my question.

The commenters are wrong if they are referring to the uncommented code.
In the statements:

g_w = p_s;

std::thread th(f3);
th.detach();
// 1. p_s destory will motify g_w (write g_w)


... starting the thread with f3 is sequenced after g_w, so g_w.lock() and g_w = p_s cannot happen simultaneously ([stmt.pre] p1):

Except as indicated, statements are executed in sequence.

Note that the original code (which you have now cleaned up in your question) contained a comment that suggests g_w is being modified within f4 after th has already started and been detached.
This could indeed be undefined behavior.

Thank you for the detaied explanation. As the comment in the aforementioned has already said that the comment in f4 is wrong.. p_s going out of scope will not affect g_w, they're different objects. Only the control-block will be adjusted. So the comment in the original code is misleading. 1. The OP want to tell the readers that he will write to the weak_ptr(i.e. g_w). 2. As the aforementioned comment in bold says the OP's understanding is wrong, the g_w would not be destroyed when p_s is out of the scope.  Note: That's why I comment out the comment in the original code.
